# android - gps - trying to get accurate distance

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to use getLatitudeE6(); but eclipse shows me error:

The method getLatitudeE6() is undefined for the type Location

If I change to getLatitude(); without E6, it works fine and there is no error. but my target is to get accurate latitude and longitude in order to calculate an accurate distance between 2 points with   distanceTo(); so I want to use getLatitudeE6

```
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            double finishLati=location.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
            double finishLongi=location.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
```

the distanceTo function:

```
               Location locationA = new Location("A");  

           locationA.setLatitude(startLati);  
           locationA.setLongitude(startLongi);  

           Location locationB = new Location("B");  

           locationB.setLatitude(finishLati);  
           locationB.setLongitude(finishLongi);  

           double distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

Answer (score 1):

using `getLatitudeE6()` vs `getLatitude()` has nothing to do with you getting an accurate location. in fact you cant use getLatitudeE6 because it does not exist as you can see from the error you are getting when trying to use it.

the problem is that you are using `getLastKnownLocation` which could be a location that is hours old or it could not even return you a location at all

Comment: also, use the `requestLocationUpdates()` method to start listening for location updates from a particular provider. Also, getting an accurate fix from GPS generally takes time so you might need to listen for updates for some time.